# Error in foreach statement in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I downloaded cruise.nlogo file from NetLogo models community. But when I run this file I got errors in this line.

```
foreach values-from patches [self] patchcolors [set pcolor-of ?1 ?2]
```

First it asked "values-from" not defined: I declared it as patches-own variable.

Second it asked "pcolor-of" not defined: I again declared it as another patches-own variable.

Third it asked at "?2": expected command.

So I am unable to understand why this error is there.  please help, I am using netlogo5.2 version. Do I need the background image file for this?

Answer (score 2):

This is very old style code.  See the NetLogo Transition Guide.  Now we write

```
(foreach sort patches patchcolors [ask ?1 [set pcolor ?2]])
```

Using `sort patches` eliminates randomization.  If you want it, you can use `[self] of patches` instead.

Comment: Why the intermediate `_color` variable? You can just do `(foreach sort patches patchcolors [ ask ?1 [ set pcolor ?2 ] ])`.

Comment: @NicolasPayette For clarity?  Apparently not.  Edited.

Comment: Thank you. but I think whole code is in old style, as after changing this statement I am again getting errors in other lines of code.

Comment: Open one or more new questions, then.

Comment: Sir, I asked a seperate question.